# Statistics question on errors and probability with Coronavirus

Tags: probability, confidence-interval, standard-error

Recently a survey in California suggested that considerably more people have been exposed to COVID-19 than previously thought. However, the testing equipment used apparently has a 1.7% false positive rate. My question is does this entirely invalidate the survey? Their numbers: N=3,300; Percent positive range 2.49% to 4.16 percent (CI not provided, I assume 95%). Error of the actual test given. I've dug through my old stats books, but I can't find a case that says ok we know that our measurement instrument is wrong by this much.

Comment: I have not read the study, but it's certainly plausible that the error rate is baked into their calculations -- that is, the interval might not be a simple $95\%$ confidence interval a la introductory statistics. (Or maybe it is!) At a first approximation, if literally none of the 3300 participants had the virus, one might expect around $1.7\%$ of them to throw a positive result on a test anyway.

Comment: Thank you and your explanation makes sense. I don't believe that the authors accounted for the error in testing equipment. But, you're saying that even with the known error rate, it's an adjustment, not an invalidation, which really was my question.

Comment: Well, to be clear: if they didn't account for that at all, it almost certainly does invalidate their findings, since under the null hypothesis random chance alone could account for a substantial share of their findings. That said, this is the kind of thing that easily *could* be accounted for and corrected in the results.